# Rebuild pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Python.
I'm having trouble with reconstructing a bad Dataframe. My Dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['id 1', 'id 2', 'test 3', 'test 4'],
               'col2': ['test 1', 'test 2',
                        'Number 6135', 'id 4'],
               'col3': ['Number 12344', 'Number 21612','id 3','Number 1131']})
```

[image]

As you can See I have the "id´s" in the first, second and third col. The same for the other Values.

My Goal is to have a Dataframe in which each Col has only the Values beginning with the Same substring like this example:

[image]

I already tried using for Loops and if statements to check if a certain Substring is in my String. if that's True I create a new Column and Write my Value inside it

```
for x in df['col1']:
if 'id' in x:
    df['newCol']=x
```

I know this code will never solve my Problem, maybe there is some pandas Function which can help me to solve this Problem

If something is not clear, just ask me I'll try my best to explain my Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` with custom key function:

```
def key_fn(x):
    if 'id' in x:
        return 0
    if 'test' in x:
        return 1
    if 'Number' in x:
        return 2
    return 3 

df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x, key=key_fn)), axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'col{}'.format(x+1))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1    col2          col3
0  id 1  test 1  Number 12344
1  id 2  test 2  Number 21612
2  id 3  test 3   Number 6135
3  id 4  test 4   Number 1131
```

---

Another version, from the comments:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, key=key_fn) for l in df.values], columns=df.columns)
print(df)
```

Comment: I had a similar idea but think this is clearer. Perhaps I'd change the apply + pd.Series which scales bad with `pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, key=custom_sort) for l in df.values], columns=df.columns)
`

Comment: @yatu I added it to the answer. I firstly tried to `df.apply(...).rename(columns=df.columns)` but that didn't work obviously :)

Comment: Yeh the answer is good. Just keep in mind that `df.apply(dp.Series(...), axis=1)` is calling the `pd.Series` constructor in each row! So it scales really badly. Nested lists and building back a df is prefered

Comment: Thank you for your answer too, i have the same question as above, what happens when i add a 4th col with a new Value like this: 'col4':['ne 315','Number 1264777','ne 1415','ne 52']' if i add my new Value "ne" tho the if Statement with a return of 3 it wont change my 4th col. The Problem is following, i asked the question with a small example, so that i can understand it better, my Dataset in realitiy consists of 17 Columns

Comment: @K2A_Dev The `key_fn` needs to be changed accordingly. Put more `if`-statements where you will return the number based on how do you want to sort the dataframe.

Comment: @AndrejKesely i changed my Function accordingly: `if 'ne' in x:
     return 3
    return 4` the Strange thing is that my 4th column won´t get any changes at all: its still as i declared it in my Dataframe `'col4':['ne 315','Number 1264777','ne 1415','ne 52']})`

Comment: @K2A_Dev To not clutter the comment section I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow - put there problematic data, expected result and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ok gotcha, Thank your for the Advice :)

Comment: i created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697425/rebuild-pandas-dataframe-with-if-statements if you want to take a look at :)

Answer (score 3):

If possible simplify solution by split values by first blank:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .melt('index')
        .assign(new = lambda x: x['value'].str.split().str[0])
        .pivot('index','new','value'))
print (df)
new          Number    id    test
index                            
0      Number 12344  id 1  test 1
1      Number 21612  id 2  test 2
2       Number 6135  id 3  test 3
3       Number 1131  id 4  test 4
```

Else you can use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
L = ['id','test','Number']

df = (df.reset_index()
        .melt('index')
        .assign(new = lambda x: x['value'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(L)})', expand=False))
        .pivot('index','new','value'))
print (df)
new          Number    id    test
index                            
0      Number 12344  id 1  test 1
1      Number 21612  id 2  test 2
2       Number 6135  id 3  test 3
3       Number 1131  id 4  test 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works great for this example. Just one question, what would happen if i add another Column to my Dataset, with the same wierd Value structure in it. Would it still work?

Comment: @K2A_Dev - Hmm, I think not, you need first select columns with problematic values like `df.reset_index()` to `df[['col1','col2','col3']].reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = df.melt()['value']
df_final = pd.DataFrame({x: s[s.str.startswith(x)].values 
                                        for x in s.str.split().str[0].unique()})

Out[27]:
     id    test        Number
0  id 1  test 3   Number 6135
1  id 2  test 4  Number 12344
2  id 4  test 1  Number 21612
3  id 3  test 2   Number 1131
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe, then use [numpy select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to reorder the names, and finally [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
(df.melt(ignore_index=False)
   .assign(variable=lambda x: np.select([x.value.str.startswith("id"),
                                          x.value.str.startswith("test"),
                                          x.value.str.startswith("Number")],
                                          ["col1", "col2", "col3"]))
    .reset_index()
    .pivot("index", "variable", "value")
    .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None))


    col1    col2    col3
0   id 1    test 1  Number 12344
1   id 2    test 2  Number 21612
2   id 3    test 3  Number 6135
3   id 4    test 4  Number 1131
```