# Rebuild pandas Dataframe with if Statements

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

As allready asked in another Question with the Title "Rebuild pandas Dataframe" i still have some Questions about going on with even more columns.

Situation:
I have a Dataframe with 4 Columns, the Values inside the Columns are pretty Random. Such as this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['id 1', 'id 2', 'test 3', 'test 4'],
           'col2': ['test 1', 'test 2',
                    'ne 5261', 'id 4'],
           'col3': ['Number 12344', 'Number 21612','id 3','Number 1131'],
           'col4':['ne 315','Number 1264777','ne 1415','ne 52']})
```

[image]

My Goal is to have a Dataframe in which each Col has only the Values beginning with the Same substring like this example:

[image]

What already worked for 3 columns is the following code (from The last Question credits to: @AndrejKesely):

```
def key_fn(x):
if 'id' in x:
    return 0
if 'test' in x:
    return 1
if 'Number' in x:
    return 2
return 3
df = pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, key=key_fn) for l in df.values], columns=df.columns)
```

print(df)

Since i now have 4 cols i added another if Statement to the Function, looking as follows:

```
def key_fn(x):
if 'id' in x:
    return 0
if 'test' in x:
    return 1
if 'Number' in x:
    return 2
if 'ne' in x:
    return 3
return 4
df = pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, key=key_fn) for l in df.values], columns=df.columns)
```

This gives me following output:

[image]

This is a small example, when i understand how it works i need to apply it to a Total of 17 Columns.
Thank you in advance for your Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['id 1', 'id 2', 'test 3', 'test 4'],
           'col2': ['test 1', 'test 2',
                    'ne 5261', 'id 4'],
           'col3': ['Number 12344', 'Number 21612','id 3','Number 1131'],
           'col4':['ne 315','Number 1264777','ne 1415','ne 52']})

def key_fn(x):
    if 'id' in x:
        return 0
    if 'test' in x:
        return 1
    if 'Number' in x:
        return 2
    if 'ne' in x:
        return 3
    return 4

out_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(sorted(np.ravel(df.values), key=key_fn)).reshape(df.shape), columns=df.columns).T
print(out_df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1    col2            col3     col4
0  id 1  test 1    Number 12344   ne 315
1  id 2  test 2    Number 21612  ne 5261
2  id 3  test 3  Number 1264777  ne 1415
3  id 4  test 4     Number 1131    ne 52
```